# Insert data from a table into another table when a trigger fires

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have 4 tables :

1. pacienti
2. cabinete
3. tmp
4. vizite.

---

```
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS tr;
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS tr; 
USE tr;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pacienti
( 
   id_pac INT NOT NULL  AUTO_INCREMENT  PRIMARY KEY
   Nume VARCHAR(40) DEFAULT  'anonim',
   Prenume VARCHAR(40) DEFAULT  'anonim',
   UNIQUE (Nume,Prenume)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cabinete 
(
   id_cab INT  NOT NULL  AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
   Denumire VARCHAR(40) DEFAULT  'nespecificat',
   UNIQUE (Denumire)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tmp 
(
   id_tmp INT(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
   DataVizita VARCHAR(10),
   OraIntrare TIME,
   ComplDate DATETIME,
   NumePacient VARCHAR(40) DEFAULT 'anonim',
   PrenumePacient VARCHAR(40) DEFAULT 'anonim',
   NumeMedic VARCHAR(40) DEFAULT 'nespecificat',
   PrenumeMedic VARCHAR(40) DEFAULT 'nespecificat',
   Cabinet VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT 'nespecificat'
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS vizite 
(
   id_viz INT(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
   Data_viz DATETIME,
   Medic_id INT(5) NOT NULL,
   Pacient_id INT(5) NOT NULL,
   Cabinet_id INT(5) NOT NULL, 
   FOREIGN KEY (`Medic_id`) REFERENCES `tr`.`medici`(`id_med`) 
   ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE CASCADE,
   FOREIGN KEY (`Pacient_id`) REFERENCES `tr`.`pacienti`(`id_pac`)
   ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE CASCADE,
   FOREIGN KEY (`Cabinet_id`) REFERENCES `tr`.`cabinete`(`id_cab`)
   ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

I have a file from which I have to import the data into the `tmp` table. 
The file (*.txt) have the next fields:

```
DataVizita | OraIntrare | NumePacient | PrenumePacient | NumeMedic | PrenumeMedic | Cabinet
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
22/04/2005 | 01:52:34   | Huruiala    |Carmen Alexandra| Garbeata  |  Panait      |   1
05/12/2005 | 04:16:02   | Schornig    |     Petre      | Rusu      | Dragos Mihai |   2
07/11/2004 | 11:24:27   | Graur       |Alexandra-Cris. | Soarece   | Dan-Cristian |   4
07/05/2008 | 06:35:44   | Rudnitchi   |     Marian     | Galescu   |George Valentin|  5
 .
 .
 .
 etc…
```

AFTER / BEFORE I made the import in the `tmp` table, I have to do some operations :

1. Create a trigger which must `concat` the `DataVizita` and `OraIntrare` into a DATETIME field (I succed by creating a function which convert  DataVizita to the right format and concatenate it with `OraIntrare`  and place the result in `ComplDate` from `tmp` table.

   ### Here is what I already did and it works:

   ```
   CREATE FUNCTION formdate(ziua VARCHAR(10), timpul TIME)RETURNS DATETIME       
   DERMINISTIC    
   RETURN 
    CONCAT (DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(ziua, '%d/%m/%Y' ) , '%Y-%m-%d' ),' ',timpul);

   DELIMITER $$
   CREATE TRIGGER upd_date BEFORE INSERT ON tmp
   FOR EACH ROW
   BEGIN
         SET new.ComplDate = formdate(new.DataVizita,new.OraIntrare);
   END$$
   DELIMITER ;
   ```
2. The second thing I have to do is to fill the `pacienti` and `cabinete` tables with data from this file.

And this one I need it because I can’t figure it out how to do it :(

Sorry for this long presentation, but I was thinking that someone will need all the details in order to understand my question.

Answer (score 0):

I have realized that actually is very simple :). The final trigger should look like this :

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS upd_date;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER upd_date BEFORE INSERT ON tmp
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN

  SET new.ComplDate=formdate(new.DataVizita,new.OraIntrare);

  INSERT INTO pacienti(nume,prenume) VALUES(new.NumePacient,new.PrenumePacient)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE nume=new.NumePacient, prenume=new.PrenumePacient;

  INSERT INTO cabinete(Denumire) VALUES(new.Cabinet)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Denumire=new.Cabinet;


END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Hope that helped somebody !